# SOAP to Rest Service Using Adapter

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap, jersey-2.0

I have a legacy project where it has SOAP webservices exposed. Now I have a requirement to convert them to rest and use it accordingly.

Can I have implementation like Jersey available to consume these soap services and then publish the same as REST?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when dealing with legacy APIs. Since REST is not a protocol by definition you can implement either:

- **Protocol Bridging Pattern**. It is a common SOA pattern that helps you transform between different protocols by using a bridging broker as intermediary. The broker holds the transformation logic. You can find [more information here](http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/protocol_bridging). Such bridges are available in most ESBs and EAI middle-wares.
  [image: Protocol Bridging Pattern]
- **Data Format Transformation Pattern**. It transforms between data formats and you can use it to transform from XML to the REST format you are using. You can implement it by putting in some internal service logic, service agents, or a dedicated transformation service. [You can see more here.](http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/data_format_transformation). You can absolutely use Jersey to build a REST Facade and transform internally from XML, or build the logic inside each service. 
  [image: Data Format Transformation Pattern]

It really depends on the size of your API and the type of solution you need. For few services I will choose the second approach - it's easier but a bit more coupled, while if I have many services I'd go for the first approach, which in my opinion abstracts transformation logic better, but it may require additional middleware and effort.

Comment: I have few services and want to go for second approach. But, can you please throw some light on examples of using Rest Facade to SOAP for data transformation.

Comment: @skanda, you asked if you can use Jersey for this - and yes, you can. In fact, you can use any framework to implement this. The solution I provided is technology agnostic and I hope my answer did help you. Alas, based on the relatively broad question you asked, I cannot provide specific code example if that is what you needed. Should you go with Jersey, you can implement a new REST API that consumes existing SOAP API with JAX-WS (see docs here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html#bnayx ) and transforms each service, according to some template or based on custom logic.